# How to get references to items (imageView) in the xml layout in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-adapter

I have the following list layout which gets inflated within a Adapter:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/gamefield_background" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/away"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"/>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:scaleX="-1"/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Inside my Adapter java class I have an setOnClickListener which listens for the clicks on the ImageViews.

The list currently is made up of 10 ImagesViews based on the following code snip:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GameViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Games game = gameList.get(position);

    holder.homeImageView.setBackgroundResource(awayResourceId);

    holder.awayImageView.setBackgroundResource(awayResourceId);

}
```

The above iterates over the gameList and adds the image for the home and away teams, which will create 5 items in the list where each item has 2 imageViews, one for home and one for away.

What I am looking to do is when a user clicks on one of the imageViews the item get selected (background highlighted), which works perfectly.

the issue right now is that I wish to unhighlight the pervious imageView selected if the user clicks on a different imageView.

Currently all I can do is highlight every imageview the user clicks.

How would I be able to get the reference to the other imageviews that each time a new imageView is clicked, a loop should be done to reset the background for pervious selected item and highlight the current selected item.

Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

Comment: `highlight *every* imageview the user clicks.` Doesn't this ring a bell to you? Get each item reference; highlight the one you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you create a top level `ImageView` and keep a reference there. This is just an idea and not a proper implementation, but you will be able to figure it out.

```java
private ImageView previousHomeIv;
private ImageView previousAwayIv;
```

Then inside your `OnBindViewHolder`, you can do something like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GameViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Games game = gameList.get(position);
    if(previousHomeIv != null) { 
    // Do Stuff Here
    }
    if(previousAwayIv!= null) { 
    // Do Stuff Here
    }

    holder.homeImageView.setBackgroundResource(awayResourceId);

    holder.awayImageView.setBackgroundResource(awayResourceId);
    previousHomeIv = holder.homeImageView;  // Assign current
    previousAwayIv= holder.awayImageView;

}
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for, how to declare the imageViews in Java!! Sorry I new to Android and had no clue!